# Css-grid: Bleed background outside container

Tags: css, background-color, css-grid

Consider the following 3-column grid layout with max-width constraint on container:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 56px minmax(56px, auto) 56px;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}

header {
  background-color: grey;
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

main {
  background-color: #2E64FE;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

aside {
  background-color: #FF0040;
  grid-column: 3 / span 1;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

footer {
  background-color: grey;
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
}

header, main, aside, footer {
  line-height: 56px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class='container'>
      <header>Header</header>
      <main>Main</main>
      <aside>Sidebar</aside>
      <footer>Footer </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ideally, I would like to bleed background of header and footer outside the container when viewport width is above max-width, but keep grid and its structure within max-width as in example (*including* inner content of header and footer).

I have considered these approaches:

- Forget max-width container, use full width container with minmax'es and position full-span divs with background-color underneath header and footer(https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OaryXj). I don't like this approach because it adds extra elements purely for styling and because it adds two extra columns (I can live with this one probably, using named columns)
- Use same approach as above, but instead of adding extra divs, use full-span header and footer with "padding: 0 calc((100% - 900px)/2);" (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BGvoxx). I don't like this approach either, because I don't understand why it works at all when 100% < 900px (why negative padding is not added) and it adds two extra columns to the grid as well.

Any other ideas? Some calc() magic with negative margins and padding on header / footer?

Comment: Something along these lines, perhaps? https://jsfiddle.net/ydj470cb/

Comment: @Michael_B this does not set the width of header and footer content-boxes to the width of main+sidebar (300px) and does not align this content-box with main+sidebar area.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ydj470cb/1/

Comment: _“I don't understand why it works at all when 100% < 900px (why negative padding is not added)”_ - because there is no such thing as a negative padding. If calc results in a value that is invalid for a property, that declaration gets ignored (same as if you had written the invalid value directly into your stylesheet.)

Comment: @Michael_B Thanks, second fiddle work perfectly well. Divided between your solution and Temani's. Pseudo elements with absolute positioning are closer to what I was looking after, but nested grids are more powerful.

Comment: @misorude You are right, confused padding with negative margins.Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if it's only about background and coloration you can use pseudo element to have the overflow effect:

```css
body {
 overflow-x:hidden;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 56px minmax(56px, auto) 56px;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}

header {
  background-color: grey;
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  position:relative;
}
header:before,
footer:before{
  content:"";
  z-index:-1;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:-100vw;
  right:-100vw;
  background:inherit;
}

main {
  background-color: #2E64FE;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

aside {
  background-color: #FF0040;
  grid-column: 3 / span 1;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

footer {
  background-color: grey;
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
  position:relative;
}

header, main, aside, footer {
  line-height: 56px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class='container'>
      <header>Header</header>
      <main>Main</main>
      <aside>Sidebar</aside>
      <footer>Footer </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

the accepted answer is amazing, but you can solve your problem by changing your markup a little bit. by changing the order of your divs and splitting the concerns of your container class with that of the grid you get the same result:

```css
body { 
 margin: 0;
 overflow-x:hidden;
}

.container {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(56px, auto);
}

header, footer {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 56px;
}

main {
  background-color: #2E64FE;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}

aside {
  background-color: #FF0040;
  grid-column: 3 / span 1;
}

header, main, aside, footer {
  line-height: 56px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">Header</div>
    </header>
    <div class="container grid">
      <main>Main</main>
      <aside>Sidebar</aside>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <div class="container">Footer</div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

the use-case where I see the accepted answer really shine is when you have multiple columns and you don't want to break the grid but extend the background color of one of the columns to the edges of the browser...

```css
body {
 overflow-x:hidden;
 margin: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(56px, auto);
}

header, footer {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 56px;
}

aside {
  background-color: #FF0040;
  grid-column: 1 / span 1;
}

main {
  background-color: #2E64FE;
  grid-column: 2 / span 2;

}

.extend-right {
  position: relative;
}

.extend-right:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  right: -100vw;
  background-color: inherit;
}

header, main, aside, footer {
  line-height: 56px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">Header</div>
    </header>
    <div class="container grid">
      <aside>Sidebar</aside>
      <main class="extend-right">Main</main>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <div class="container">Footer</div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```