# Full width background with viewport-centered grid layout

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a simple grid layout to display a single column of elements like this:

```
body
{
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    grid-auto-flow: row;
}

body > * {
    width: 75vw;
    max-width: 45rem;
}
```

`body`'s children are `header`, `main` and `footer`. I would like to define a background (color) for the `header` to cover the full width of the viewport without its content overflowing the area defined by the CSS instructions above. I found a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53110368/span-background-color-across-viewport-width) of [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53550846/css-grid-bleed-background-outside-container) pointing to pseudo elements, but they seem to require a different grid setup. Is there any simple way to get the full width background color without complicating the very elegant CSS too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `border-image`: https://css-tip.com/overflowing-background/

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
}

body > * {
  width: 75vw;
  max-width: 45rem;
  padding-block: 1em;
}

main {
 border-image: conic-gradient(lightblue 0 0) fill 0//0 100vw;
}
```

```html
<header>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras a justo interdum, gravida tellus quis, iaculis tortor. Suspendisse quis lectus scelerisque, porta felis in, faucibus dui. Vivamus lobortis pellentesque urna vel ornare. Nulla est purus, tincidunt a ante in, efficitur commodo massa. Curabitur ultrices mollis</header>
<main>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras a justo interdum, gravida tellus quis, iaculis tortor. Suspendisse quis lectus scelerisque, porta felis in, faucibus dui. Vivamus lobortis pellentesque urna vel ornare. Nulla est purus, tincidunt a ante in, efficitur commodo massa. Curabitur ultrices mollis</main>
<footer>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras a justo interdum, gravida tellus quis, iaculis tortor. Suspendisse quis lectus scelerisque, porta felis in, faucibus dui. Vivamus lobortis pellentesque urna vel ornare. Nulla est purus, tincidunt a ante in, efficitur commodo massa. Curabitur ultrices mollis</footer>
```

Comment: That's amazing, thank you! Just one more question: This border-image shortcut contains a source (`conic-gradient`), a slice value (`fill`) and a width (`100vw`). But what is the `0//0` value?

Comment: @janeden the slice is `fill 0` and `0 100vw` is the outset not the width. The syntax is `<slice>/<width>/<outset>` but I don't need to specify the width so I keep it empty